# How to change a localhost server into a dns server?

Tags: node.js, dns, localhost

I am working with node.js and have created a basic http server. I am already using localtunnel to get it through to other people for testing, but I want to consider buying my own domain name and using it for my server. How do I do this, what should I buy (e.g. just the name, or what?) Where should I buy it, and how do I use It with my http server? I don't mind using other programs, but would not want to use a giant complex node.js file in my project. I have researched this in a lot of places, but haven't seemed to be able to find a definite answer. Please help me, and if this is a repeat, PLEASE tell me the original. Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad cpelnng, -Maze

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Heroku` to host your code (if domain name like `myapp.herokuapp.com` is fine with you). It has a free limit and then paid. You can add your code to Github or DropBox and deploy your code to `Heroku` using it or you can directly upload the code onto Heroku using Heroku git (using the Heroku cli). You can lookup more at https://www.heroku.com/

One thing to note that port of the http server in the node.js code should be `process.env.PORT`

Comment: I was thinking something more like www.mydomain.com would be better than myapp.domainthing.com

Comment: You can buy a domain from somewhere like [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com/) and add it in your `Heroku Dashboard` after deploying your webapp on `Heroku`

Comment: This might work... I was also wondering how real websites do this, like google for example.

Comment: In that case, you need to obtain a `static IP address` for your system from your `ISP` (a point to note is if you use a router, it should be configured such that all requests it receives for the `static IP` should be forwarded to the system that has the node server running), and buy a domain with a dns from somewhere like [GoDaddy](https://godaddy.com/) (usually the DNS comes free with the domain) and then get it to point to your `static IP address`